# Could not open data connection to port xxxxx: Connection timed out

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am using Windows command line to ftp a file.  I was able to do it successfully one time, and every time since then doesn't work.  I'm not sure what I changed.

After running the put file_name.txt command from within ftp I wait for ~ 3 minutes and I get the following error message:

```
425 Could not open data connection to port XXXXX: Connection timed out
```

The server does actually have the file but it is 0 bytes long.

I disabled firewall and I tried `quote pasv` after doing some searching around the web for this error.

Any advice?

```
ftp <myhost>.com
Connected to <myhost>.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 9 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 12:30. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
User (<myhost>.com:(none)): <myusername>
331 User <myusername> OK. Password required
Password:
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> cd ftpTest
250 OK. Current directory is /ftpTest
ftp> quote pasv
227 Entering Passive Mode (97,74,182,128,196,125)
ftp> put test.txt
200 PORT command successful
425 Could not open data connection to port 41084: Connection timed out
ftp>
```

NOTE: I'm on Windows 8

Comment: We need more information. What is the network structure like?--e.g., is simply a local a router <--> computer?

Comment: godaddy shared hosting server --> small business with 1 router --> my computer w/ internal ip.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that your dont have a Firewall blocking you.  Check out this Wiki Link and see if anything helps:  https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration

Comment: I have verified the server isn't blocking it, and to the best of my knowledge I checked locally and there was no problem.  I disabled McAfee, which also disables windows firewall.  Plus I ran the batch as administrator.

Answer (score -1):

its windows blocking it
need to have public and private both clicked on in "allow a app through windows firewall"

see attached
[windows firewall allow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeSUm.png)

Comment: I would suggest you make your answer more clear, correctly and cleanly written.